# How to make jquery radio button function run on page load?

Tags: jquery

EDIT: Thanks for the replies! Unfortunately using .trigger('change') or .change() to manually run the event doesn't work properly. If the user changes the value of one set of radio buttons, but doesn't change the other, the maths doesn't add up. Any other suggestions?

I have [this form](http://jsfiddle.net/ZLKCL/)

It mostly works as I want it to, but I would like the jquery function to run on page load as well as when the user changes the radio button selection. How would I do this?

```
var price=$("input[name='courierrepairprice']").val();
price = Number(price.replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g,""));
var postage_out=0;
var postage_in=0
$("input[name='outwardpostage']").change(function()
{
   postage_out=$(this).val();
   tot_price=parseFloat(price,10)+parseFloat(postage_out,10)+parseFloat(postage_in,10)
   tot_price=tot_price.toFixed(2)

   $('.tot_price').text('£'+tot_price); 
});
$("input[name='returnpostage']").change(function()
{
   postage_in=$(this).val();   
   tot_price=parseFloat(price,10)+parseFloat(postage_out,10)+parseFloat(postage_in,10)
   tot_price=tot_price.toFixed(2)
   $('.tot_price').text('£'+tot_price);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [.trigger('change')](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) or .change() to manually simulate an event

```
var price=$("input[name='courierrepairprice']").val();
price = Number(price.replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g,""));
var postage_out=0;
var postage_in=0;

function calculate(){
    console.log('calc', price, postage_out, postage_in)
    var tot_price = price + postage_out + postage_in;
    tot_price=tot_price.toFixed(2)

    $('.tot_price').text('£' + tot_price);
}

$("input[name='outwardpostage']").change(function() {
    postage_out = parseFloat($(this).val());
    calculate();
}).filter(':checked').trigger('change');
$("input[name='returnpostage']").change(function() {
    postage_in =  parseFloat($(this).val());   
    calculate();
}).filter(':checked').trigger('change');
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/kdK9H/)

Comment: Actually it doesn't work properly :-/ . The maths doesn't add up if a user clicks on one set of radio buttons but doesn't click the other

Comment: @Chris I didn't look at the calculation portion since the question was regarding page load

Comment: The calculation portion worked fine before. I'm guessing it's because the ".trigger('change')" part only runs the event for that function, rather than running both functions. Should I open a new question for this?

Comment: Thanks Arun I really appreciate it :-)

Answer (score 0):

call your change event again after at the end of the change function to autoinvoke the change call....

```
 $("input[name='outwardpostage']").change(function()
 {
  postage_out=$(this).val();
  tot_price=parseFloat(price,10)+parseFloat(postage_out,10)+parseFloat(postage_in,10)
  tot_price=tot_price.toFixed(2)

  $('.tot_price').text('£'+tot_price); 
}).change();  //<--here ..same for other change event
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Unfortunately it doesn't work properly :-( . The maths doesn't add up if a user clicks on one set of radio buttons but doesn't click the other

Comment: not getting you.. what do you mean... can u show some example

Comment: Yes certainly - you can see it in Arun's fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/kdK9H/

Comment: I'm guessing it's because the ".trigger('change')" part only runs the event for that function, rather than running both functions.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to move code inside the change function to obvious function and call it ones on load and then in change listeners.

```
$(document).load(function(){ 
    var doAction = function(){

    };

    $("input[name='returnpostage']").change(function()
    {
      doAction();
    };

    doAction();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can try this one also

```
var price=$("input[name='courierrepairprice']").val();
price = Number(price.replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g,""));
var postage_out=0;
 var postage_in=0
$("input[name='outwardpostage']").change(function()
{
postage_out=$(this).val();
tot_price=parseFloat(price,10)+parseFloat(postage_out,10)+parseFloat(postage_in,10)
tot_price=tot_price.toFixed(2)

$('.tot_price').text('£'+tot_price);
}).change();
$("input[name='returnpostage']").change(function()
{
postage_in=$(this).val();   
tot_price=parseFloat(price,10)+parseFloat(postage_out,10)+parseFloat(postage_in,10)
tot_price=tot_price.toFixed(2)
$('.tot_price').text('£'+tot_price);
}).change();
```

JS Fiddle Demo [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dubeynee/ZLKCL/1/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Unfortunately it doesn't work properly :-( . The maths doesn't add up if a user clicks on one set of radio buttons but doesn't click the other

Answer (score 0):

[**DEMO FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZLKCL/2/)

code-

```
var price=$("input[name='courierrepairprice']").val();
price = Number(price.replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g,""));
var postage_out=0;
var postage_in=0;
var fndo = function()
{
 postage_in=$(this).val()||postage_in;   
 tot_price=parseFloat(price,10)+parseFloat(postage_out,10)+parseFloat(postage_in,10)
 tot_price=tot_price.toFixed(2)
 $('.tot_price').text('£'+tot_price);
};

$("input[name='outwardpostage'], input[name='returnpostage']").change(fndo);
$(document).ready(fndo);
```

Here I used a function object and called on change and document ready, added a condition for `postage_in` to prevent being `undefined` when called by document because there will be no value for document

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately it doesn't work. In your fiddle the total price displayed on page load doesn't take postage costs into account.